# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor del atributo height del componente mat-form-field de Angular Material 15?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hola estimada comunidad , tengo un problema para cambiar la altura del componente mat-form-field de angular material 15.1. Estoy desarrollando un proyecto y tengo este html

```
<div class="dashboard-search-toolbar">
        <form class="dashboard-search-form">
            <mat-form-field class="dashboard-search-field" appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Buscar servicios</mat-label>
                <input matInput aria-label="Buscar servicios" [formControl]="menuCtrl">
                <mat-icon color="accent" matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
            <br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Y necesito ajustar el tamaño de la altura del `mat-form-field` a un valor de 50px; para esto he aplicado la siguiente regla CSS

```
mat-form-field{
  height: 50px;
}
```

Sin embargo tengo este resultado:

[image: resultado de aplicar regla css]

Y al intentar escribir en el input, el componente se comporta de esta manera:

[image: comportamiento del elemento input].

¿Cuá es la manera correcta de realizar esa modificación de este componente?. Se lo agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Puedes intentar ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
    height: 50px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Debería de funcionar:

```
mat-form-field {
   height: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: He intentando con tu solución, sin embargo la distorción se mantiene. He probado algunas soluciones por el estilo, incluso con el :host ::ng-deep, aunque según la documentación está obsoleto, y de igual manera no funciona

Comment: Probaste quítandole la clase al `mat-form-field`?

Answer (score 0):

**Custom style for outline appearance:**

```
    .mat-sm > .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
       height: 35px !important;
    }
    .mat-sm > .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper.mdc-text-field--outlined .mat-mdc-form- 
    field-infix  {
      padding-top: 8px !important;
    }
   .mat-sm >  .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper .mat-mdc-form-field-flex .mat-mdc- 
    floating-label {
      top: 17px;
    }
    .mat-sm >  .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper .mat-mdc-form-field-flex .mdc-floating- 
    label--float-above {
      top: 28px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="font-weight-bold mat-sm w-30 mt-2" 
    color="accent">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Guaru, estás en SOes, el idioma soportado es el español, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites tu respuesta, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, de esa forma será mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos. ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.